# Is it possible to look up a feed post that a user has posted via my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth-2.0, feed

I would like to use the Graph API to determine if a feed post id is valid. When I've tried a normal Graph call, however, it always returns an empty array. Do I need to use an app oauth token or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a acess token with **read_stream** privilegies to check if the feed really exist.

But you can only read feeds from the current user or related to him or his friends.